# Dupal cache and GeoIP - how can I have both?

Tags: 6, caching

Drupal 6 installation, 13 languages. Users are being redirected to the correct language based on browser language and we have a link that includes visitors's country code (i get this code VIA GeoIP API).
Problem is - if Drupal cache is enabled, it caches the pages and users are being redirected to different languages, and also country codes are wrong. If I disable cache, everything works, but the site is much slower.

Is there a way to use cache AND have GeoIP work correctly?

Comment: This is probably best as a feature request in the module's issue queue, though it looks like the module is no longer being actively developed.  The module likely needs to be rewritten to offer this kind of feature.

Comment: GeoIp provides APIs like `geoip_country_code($ip_addr)` which returns Country code for that IP. You could use this API in `hook_boot()` (This hook is independent of cache and will always be invoked). Based on country code you could then redirect using `header`